# Converting cartesian parametric coordinates to cylindrical or spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, parametric

How could I change these parametric equations in cartesian coordinates to cylindrical or spherical coordinates?

$x(t) = \cos(t)$

$y(t) = \sin(t)$

$z(t) = \sin(t)$

If someone could give me some tips it would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cylindrical coordinates we have
$$
\rho \cos \theta=\cos t
$$$$
\rho \sin \theta=\sin t
$$
$$
z=\sin t
$$
and, for $-\pi/2< \theta< \pi/2$ this gives
$$
\theta =t ,\quad, \quad \rho=1 \quad ,\quad z=\sin t
$$
I think  that you can solve in the same manner for the spherical coordinates

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful, I think I can do it with spherical coordinates now.